# How to run a node js file (that makes a api call and puts data into a sheet) by clicking on a button in html

Tags: javascript, node.js, smartsheet-api

I tried to get some answers here on stack overflow but I don't really understand it.

I want to execute my node js script by clicking on a button in html.
The node js file pulls data from an excel sheet and puts it into a specific sheet.

The node js file works perfectly if I run it in the console. But how do I connect this file with a button in html? It is not possible just to call the function, because the node js file is running on a server.

**This is the function I want to execute by clicking on a button**

```
function importData(){
    //import the smartsheet
    ss.sheets.importXlsxSheet(options)
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("Created sheet '" + result.result.id + "' from excel file");
        
        // Load entire sheet
        ss.sheets.getSheet({ id: result.result.id })
            .then(function(sourceSheet) {
                console.log("Loaded: " + sourceSheet.rows.length + " rows from sheet '" + sourceSheet.name + "'");
                console.log("Done");

                    //copy every row from sourcesheet in a array 
                    const sourceSheetRows = sourceSheet.rows;
                    writeRowsinArray(result, sourceSheetRows);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to trigger something on a server from a browser is to make an HTTP request to it.

So set up an HTTP endpoint that will trigger the function (e.g. by running a server built around the express module or using a cloud service such as AWS Lambda) then use client-side JS to make the request (e.g. with the Fetch API).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call an exposed api for that.
Your nodeJs script have to listen on an endpoint.

From JavaScript in your html you have to call your api using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).